# 3.3 geometry node uv map display Error？

Tags: geometry-nodes

## blender3.3

### uv edge problem

> **I don't want the stuff marked in the red box**

[image]

### geometry node:

[image]

### textures:

[image]

### uv

[image]

### blender file:

[demo](https://github.com/ZeronoFreya/Gallery/blob/master/demo.blend)

Where is the problem?

Comment: it's not clear what you are asking for. what result are you expecting?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I don't want the stuff marked in the red box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the last point is located in two different positions in the UV map:

[image]

To deal with it, convert domain to face corner:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much